# when i trigger this jquery event, other element in other row of table got triggered as well which i want to prevent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

when i trigger this jquery event, other element in other row of table got triggered as well which i want to prevent

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".Trigger_modi").delegate("a", "click",function(e){

                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var tnp = $(this).attr('id');
                    window.alert("tnp: "+tnp);
                    document.getElementById('modi_i').value=tnp;
                    $('#myDiv').html('<input type="button" name="modify" id="mD" value='+tnp+'  onclick="modiTest.jsp">');  


                    $('.inner_element_1').html('<input type="text" name="subject" value="">');



                    $('.inner_element_2').html('<h2 > yahoo</h2>');
                    $('.inner_element_3').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');

                    $('.inner_element_4').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');
                    $('.inner_element_5').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');

                    var t = document.getElementById('modi_i').value
                    window.alert("t: "+t);

                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                });
            });
```

This is jquery function that would be triggered if i click "a" tag.

and ***this would make table look like this ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓***

[This is description of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX4os.jpg)

```
 <div class="Trigger_modi"> <div class="inner_element_2"><a id="<%=i %>">수정</a></div></div>
```

and this html code is wrapped by for loop which i suspect that it might be reason why i am getting trouble with

anyone suggest i could try?

```
   <a class="Trigger" id="<%=idx %>"> <%=subject %></a>
       <div class="Slider slideup">
       <div id="Actual"><!-- 누르면 본문내용 보게됨. -->
               </form>

      <jsp:useBean id="bdao" class="Bob.Community.CommunityDAO" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
      <jsp:useBean id="bdto" class="Bob.Community.CommunityDTO"></jsp:useBean>


            <div class="inner_element_1"><%=content %></div>



       <div class="Trigger_modi"> <div class="inner_element_2"><a id="<%=i %>">Modify</a></div></div>
            <div class="">
            <div id="Actual_modi">



            </div>
         </div>



         <div class="inner_element_3"><a href="noticeDelete.jsp?i=<%=i %>">Delete</a></div>   

         <div class="inner_element_4"></div>   
         <div class="inner_element_5"></div>   


             </div>
       </div>
```

**

### Edit 1) it works, appreciate for all you comment, reply

### **

i first suspected that the problem was caused by for loop, and it turned out to be right. 
[assume for loop loops 5times.]
when for loop finished and in javascript function triggers,  `the inner_element_(number)` --> all 25 element(for loop 5 times * 5element) is set to same html tag for each number of element. i change it to something like `<div class="inner_element_<%=idx%>">` which makes possible for 25 element to have a different class value individually. and it works fine. thanks

**

### Edit 2) All I did to make it completely work fine : turned out Integrity problem

**

1. `<div class="inner_element_(number)` to `<div class="inner_element_<%=idx %>`
2. `$('.inner_element_(number)')` to `$('.inner_element_'+tnp)`
3. and i delete `e.stopPropagation();
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();`
4. and i change `$(".Trigger_modi").delegate("a", "click",function(e){` to `$(".Trigger_modi").click( function (frm) {`

Comment: Show the `HTML` please

Comment: Since you are using `<%=i %>` and as far as I know you can not use only number for ID

Comment: `$('.inner_element_2').html('<h2 > yahoo</h2>');`  <-- you select all the elements on the page.... So of course they will all change.

Comment: ah yeah. i see what you are saying thanks

Comment: you mean, i need to separate their name? right ? i see also i delete my file, i got your point thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.inner_element_1').html('<input type="text" name="subject" value="">');


$('.inner_element_2').html('<h2 > yahoo</h2>');
$('.inner_element_3').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');

$('.inner_element_4').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');
$('.inner_element_5').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');

var t = document.getElementById('modi_i').value
```

In the above code you are assigning html to all `.inner_element_1`, `.inner_element_2`, `.inner_element_3`, `.inner_element_4` and `.inner_element_5` which `jQuery` will look all element with class `inner_element_[1-5]` of the **whole** page. So it may not raised another row event, it may just simply a HTML binding logic error in this case.

Try to revise your function as follow:

```
$(".Trigger_modi").each(function () {
    var $Trigger_modi = $(this);
    $Trigger_modi.delegate("a", "click",function(e){

        e.stopPropagation();
        var tnp = $(this).attr('id');
        window.alert("tnp: "+tnp);
        document.getElementById('modi_i').value=tnp;
        $('#myDiv').html('<input type="button" name="modify" id="mD" value='+tnp+'  onclick="modiTest.jsp">');  


        $Trigger_modi.find('.inner_element_1').html('<input type="text" name="subject" value="">');

        $Trigger_modi.find('.inner_element_2').html('<h2 > yahoo</h2>');
        $Trigger_modi.find('.inner_element_3').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');

        $Trigger_modi.find('.inner_element_4').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');
        $Trigger_modi.find('.inner_element_5').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');

        var t = document.getElementById('modi_i').value
        window.alert("t: "+t);

        event.stopImmediatePropagation();    
});
```

### Edit 1 -

Please wrap the above code inside a `$(document).ready()` and also revise the first 3 lines as follow:

```
$(".Trigger_modi").each(function () {
        var $Trigger_modi = $(this);
        $Trigger_modi.find("a").on("click", function(e){
    ....
```

### Edit 2 -

After looked into your `noticeList.jsp`, I think you have to revise all your elements that contain the `id` attribute inside the for loop since it is not allowed to contains 2(or more) elements share the same `id` in HTML.

Also, since you are looping via `for(int i= (n-1) ;i<=(n-1)+x;i++)`, it is not allowed in HTML that using digit only in the `id` attribute, so you have to revise your `a` element as follow as well:
`<div class="Trigger_modi"> <div class="inner_element_2"><a id="<%=i %>" data-id="<%=i %>">Modify</a></div>`

After that, you could give a class name for your td as follow:

```
<td class="TriggerCell">
<form name=f>
```

And revise the code in edit 1 as follow:

```
$(".TriggerCell").each(function () {
        var $TriggerCell = $(this);
        $TriggerCell.find(".Trigger_modi a").on("click", function(e){
            var tnp = $(this).attr("data-id");
    ....
```

Comment: thanks man i see what's your point but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. iam gonna have to find out what s wrong

Comment: May I know how you define 'doesn't work' since it means a lot of out come, however, does `window.alert("tnp: "+tnp);` fired twice when you clicked on 1 `<a>` element?

Comment: ah yeah. I have a previous (".Trigger") a tag Class that trigger initial click action (note, Trigger_modi is a second_action after Trigger) but if i change my code as you wrote, it does not respond at all so i mentioned doesn't work. thanks man

Comment: I have found your html is a little bit messy, for example, you are having a `</form>` after the `<div id="Actual">`. And codes `<a class="Trigger">.....<div class="inner_element_5">` if in a for loop, you should not have a `<div id="Actual">` and `<div id="Actual_modi">` which the ID property means an unique name.

Comment: Also, may I know which file am I looking for? there is lot of it

Comment: thanks so much, i am still trying to figure out what is going on here and things are so much complicated than i expected, again i wish you have a blessing day

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".Trigger_modi").on("click","a",function(e){

                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var tnp = $(this).attr('id');
                    window.alert("tnp: "+tnp);
                    document.getElementById('modi_i').value=tnp;
                    $('#myDiv').html('<input type="button" name="modify" id="mD" value='+tnp+'  onclick="modiTest.jsp">');  


                    $(this).parent().find('.inner_element_1').html('<input type="text" name="subject" value="">');



                    $(this).parent().find('.inner_element_2').html('<h2 > yahoo</h2>');
                    $(this).parent().find('.inner_element_3').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');

                    $(this).parent().find('.inner_element_4').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');
                    $(this).parent().find('.inner_element_5').html('<h2>yahoo</h2>');

                    var t = document.getElementById('modi_i').value
                    window.alert("t: "+t);

                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                });
            });
```

Comment: it does not change to yahoo window.alert("tnp: "+tnp); window.alert("t: "+t); also doesn't work

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: You should state the problem when you answer, not just give code.

Comment: sorry i delete my file